# Link to .exe doesn't launch Wine

Tags: wine

When I create a symlink on a .exe and I double click it, nothing happens. 
Instead, if I double click the original file, Wine opens automatically. 
Why is this? How can be changed? Can the situation be different with another kind of link?

NB: I don't want a .desktop, only a symlink.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a comment that turned out to be the answer:

> Ah...symlink. The Wine symlink probably doesn't work because the
>   ".exe" requires path to the "working directory". Unfortunately symlink
>   does not support this. You will need to create a wrapper script (how?
>   answered here: [askubuntu.com/questions/51314/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51314/symbolic-link-doesnt-use-target-working-directory)… ); then either use the
>   wrapper script as a launcher, or keep it in the ".exe" folder and
>   symlink to it.

I'm not sure what you mean with "soft link". But when I need to create a Wine shortcut launcher I just start GEdit and create a file like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open    
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=MY APPLICATION NAME
Comment=THINGS I HAVE TO SAY ABOUT THE APPLICATION
Exec=sh -c "cd /PATH_TO_EXE_FOLDER; wine FILENAME.exe"
Categories=ENGINERRING;GRAPHICS;ETC
Icon=/PATH_TO_ICON_IMAGE_FILE
```

Then save the file wherever I want as a ".desktop", for example: "MyWineApp.desktop".

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Well, I don't want a .desktop, but only a symlink.

Comment: Ah...symlink. The Wine symlink probably doesn't work because the ".exe" requires path to the "working directory". Unfortunately symlink does not support this. You will need to create a wrapper script (how? answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/51314/symbolic-link-doesnt-use-target-working-directory ); then either use the wrapper script as a launcher, or keep it in the ".exe" folder and symlink to it.

Comment: Can you add the comment to your answer? In such a way I can mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

I know the best and easiest way !

Open /home/.local/share/wine/programs And you can see your wine apps folders open your app folder , there is your_app_name.desktop , copy it to desktop and right click on it , and then , left click on Allow Launching

Congratulations !!! Your app shortcut is on your desktop , enjoy !

Sorry if my English is not good