# How Can I Run an Shell Script With .desktop Config File?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, .desktop, sh

I am trying to run a shell script with a `.desktop` file but it doesn't seem to work, producing an error of `There was an error launching the application` at each attempt. I have the sh and .desktop files set the executable.

**.desktop file:**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Craftbukkit Server
Comment=run server
Exec="/home/ubuntu-gnome/Documents/Craftbukkit/run.sh"
Icon=/home/ubuntu-gnome/Documents/Craftbukkit/craftbukkit.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

**The script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar /home/ubuntu-gnome/Documents/Craftbukkit/craftbukkit.jar -o false
```

All paths are correct.

**Methods I Have Tried:**

- `Exec="/home/ubuntu-gnome/Documents/Craftbukkit/run.sh"`
- `Exec='/home/ubuntu-gnome/Documents/Craftbukkit/run.sh'`
- `Exec=/home/ubuntu-gnome/Documents/Craftbukkit/run`
- `Exec="/home/ubuntu-gnome/Documents/Craftbukkit/run.sh"`
- `Exec=gnome-terminal -e "/home/ubuntu-gnome/Documents/Craftbukkit/run.sh"`
- `Exec=bash -c 'cd /home/ubuntu-gnome/Documents/Craftbukkit/ && ./run.sh'`

Conspicuously, I have tried many methods. Can anyone assist me with a resolution to this?

Comment: First question: does the script work when you run it from a terminal window?

Comment: Yes It does. I have been using it from the terminal with `./run.sh` for many months now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's Everyone for the help. I realized that I had something wrong with my `.desktop` file. I noticed that the properties of the .desktop file were different to that of the other .desktop files in `/usr/share/applications`, in it that there were no Description, Command or Comment text areas in mine.

I saved the .desktop file of Color Picker to the desktop and I substituted my information in, which made it work.

This is what the properties->Basic of the .desktop file is.

[image: properties]

**The Script**

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Name=Minecraft-Server Comment=Run the Minecraft
Craftbukkit Server
Icon=/home/ubuntu-gnome/Documents/Craftbukkit/craftbukkit.png
Exec='/home/ubuntu-gnome/Documents/Craftbukkit/run.sh' 
Terminal=true
Type=Application 
Categories=Minecraft;Server;CraftBukkit;
```

Answer (score 3):

Few potential issues:

1. Your script needs a shebang on its first line... it should look like:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   /usr/bin/java ...
   ```
2. Your script needs to be marked as executable:

   ```
   chmod +x /path/to/script.sh
   ```
3. Your `.desktop` file **also** needs to be executable ([security policy stuff apparently](https://askubuntu.com/a/419657/449)):

   ```
   chmod +x /path/to/desktop-file.desktop
   ```

Comment: Regarding step 3. why question: [Permission of a .desktop file](http://askubuntu.com/a/419657/36315)

Comment: The last one should not be necessary when run from Dash and stored in `~/.local.share/applications` or `/usr/share/applications` (not on my system anyway)

Comment: Still produces the same error.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would use for creating the ".desktop" file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open    
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=MY APPLICATION NAME
Comment=THINGS I HAVE TO SAY ABOUT THE APPLICATION
Exec=sh -c "cd /PATH_TO_SH_FILE_FOLDER; FILENAME.sh"
Categories=ENGINERRING;GRAPHICS;ETC
Icon=/PATH_TO_ICON_IMAGE_FILE
```

For above, change the all-capital portions of the code to fit your context (which doesn't have to be all-capital). You can add `Terminal = true` if you want to see the terminal window.

Modified from an answer I gave to a related question here: [Link to .exe doesn't launch Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541317/link-to-exe-doesnt-launch-wine/541405?noredirect=1#comment741417_541405)

Comment: that is just replacing in OP's last attempt "&&" by ";". won't change anything.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Thanks @JacobVlijm for pointing out. Glad it is sorted out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use always abolute paths in those scripts. Find out what path the java executable has with:

```
which java
```

Then use that as the path in yout script:

```
/path/to/java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar /path/to/craftbukkit.jar -o false
```

Note that you also should give the complete path to `craftbukkit.jar`.